# How to bind a dropdownlist depending on value of another dropdown

Tags: asp.net

In My case using cascade dropdownlist for Country,State,City and MainRoad.

It works fine on selection but i want to that when country items change onkeyup or onkeydown that time load depended state items same for state,city or MainRoad.

How can do this please provide help full solutions.

My code is:

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager><div><table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3"><tr><td>Country</td><td><asp:DropDownList ID="dr_country" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList><cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cas_country" runat="server"Category="Country" TargetControlID="dr_country" UseContextKey="true" LoadingText="Loading ......" PromptText="Select Country" PromptValue="" ServiceMethod="BindCountrydropdown" ServicePath="CascadeDropDownService.asmx"> </cc1:CascadingDropDown></td></tr>
  <tr><td>State</td><td><asp:DropDownList ID="dr_state" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cas_state" runat="server" Category="State" TargetControlID="dr_State" ParentControlID="dr_country" LoadingText="Loading ......" PromptText="Select State" PromptValue="" ServiceMethod="BindStatedropdown" ServicePath="CascadeDropDownService.asmx"></cc1:CascadingDropDown></td></tr><tr><td>City</td><td><asp:DropDownList ID="dr_city" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList><cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cas_city" runat="server" Category="Region" TargetControlID="dr_city" ParentControlID="dr_State" PromptValue=""  LoadingText="Loading Cities..." PromptText="Select City" ServiceMethod="BindCitydropdown" ServicePath="CascadeDropDownService.asmx"> </cc1:CascadingDropDown>
 </td></tr><tr><td>MainRoad</td><td><asp:DropDownList ID="dr_mainroad" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cas_mainroad" runat="server" Category="Mainroad" TargetControlID="dr_MainRoad" ParentControlID="dr_city" PromptValue="" LoadingText="Loading Main Road..." PromptText="Select Mainroad" ServiceMethod="BindMainroadropdown" ServicePath="CascadeDropDownService.asmx"></cc1:CascadingDropDown></td></tr></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily without using ajax. Just Bind The `dr_state` in `selecedindexchange` event of `dr_country`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dr_country" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="dr_country_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and in code behind

```
protected void dr_country_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Bind you dr_state dynamically here with parameter country.
}
```

and same for city and street address.